# For x > 0, when does e^x = x!

Tags: functions, taylor-expansion

Looking at it on Desmos, it appears to be about 5.29, but what does this number mean, and how can it be shown in a mathematical proof?

In response to comments:

x is a real number greater than 0

x! is expandable by the gamma function so x can be a non-integer (which it will end up being)

How do I show in a mathematical proof what value of x where x > 0 causes e^x = x! to be true?

Comment: What is x? An integer? A real number?...

Comment: See also [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5Ex+%3D+x%21)

Comment: It's not uncommon to define $x!$ for noninteger $x$ by $x!=\Gamma(x+1)$, where $\Gamma$ is the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function). The solution is only approximate, a more accurate approximation would be $x\simeq5.290316093119770710722225818631172747999820188$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut How did you find that approximation?

Comment: From lhf's comment most likely...

Comment: It seems that you might be asking an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Your question seems to be indicating that you want to find the point where $e^x=x!$.  On the other hand, your last line is asking whether a point where $e^x=x!$ exists.  It seems that you're asking how to find the point $5.29\ldots$ when you really want to know that a crossing point exists.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Thanks, fixed XY problem. I would like to know how to find that point. I was thinking the Taylor Series of e^x might be relatable to x! in such a way that you could find an x > 0 that satisfies the above equation without immediately using an approximation method.

Comment: The point is likely some transcendental point which doesn't have a name.  There's not really anything to prove since the point is *defined* as the intersection point of $e^x$ and $\Gamma(x+1)$.  In other words, there's no other representation of the point to prove that it's equal to.

Answer (score 1):

From the last line of your question, it seems that you might be more interested in the existence of a point that satisfies $e^x=\Gamma(x+1)$ and not its actual value.

You can know that a point where $e^x=\Gamma(x+1)$ exists as follows: Consider the function $f(x)=e^x-\Gamma(x+1)$.  Since both $e^x$ and $\Gamma(x+1)$ are continuous for $x>0$, $f(x)$ is a continuous function.  When $x=1$, $f(1)=e-1$, which is positive since $e>1$.  When $x=10$, on the other hand, $f(10)=e^{10}-10!$ is negative, which we can see as follows: since $e<3$, $f(10)<3^{10}-10!$.  We observe that $1<2$, $3<4$, $3<5$, $3<6$, $3<7$, $3<8$, and $3^2<10$.  Therefore,
\begin{align*}
10!&=1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5\cdot6\cdot7\cdot8\cdot9\cdot10\\
&>1\cdot 1\cdot 3\cdot 3\cdot3\cdot3\cdot3\cdot3\cdot3^2\cdot3^2=3^{10}.
\end{align*}
Therefore, by the intermediate value theorem, there is some $x$ between $1$ and $10$ so that $f(x)=0$.  Now, with better approximations (or Newton's method) you can approximate this point quite well.

I am not sure that the point $5.29\dots$ is really interesting on its own.